# Are formal parameters and explicit parameters the same in Java?

Tags: java, programming-languages

I know that explicit parameters are those that are listed within the parenthesis of method calls. I also know that formal parameters are the names of the parameters in the method heading.

In this code, does it make sense to call **x** both an formal and explicit parameter?

```
public int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

And if so, is there any case where you would have a formal parameter that is not an explicit parameter?

I'm trying to think of all the cases that seem to be possible -- formal explicit, formal implicit, actual explicit, and actual implicit. Are all of these possible and valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about it but I think this is correct:

> In this code, does it make sense to call x both an formal and explicit parameter?

Yes, it's both formal and explicit.

> is there any case where you would have a formal parameter that is not an explicit parameter?

`this` is a formal implicit parameter.

We already addressed when they are explicit and implicit they will be actual when you will actually call the code.

```
add(1,2); // 1 and 2 are actual explicit parameters
"a".length(); // "a" is the actual implicit parameter
```